# How to change the HTML source code after calling a curl_init?

Tags: php, javascript, html, curl

I curl_exec a curl_init
I want to make some alterations in the source code of the initialised curl session.(in PHP,JAVASCRIPT or ANYthing else)
Anybody got any idea?
Please help

Comment: to what purpose? taking HTML from a CURL session to then be output to the browser? details?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code out:

```
  $curl = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936870/how-to-change-the-html-source-code-after-calling-a-curl-init");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $html = curl_exec($curl); // run CURL
  curl_close($curl); 
  echo $html; // and finally, return $html
```

> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

This will return the html code, and after that you can use another function to change this like: `str_replace` or `preg_replace`